# An indentation problem with TikZ nodes and foreign document classes (babel)

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, document-classes

I'm new to LaTeX and i'm struggling with TikZ, especially flowcharts.
I'm dutch and therefor I'm using the documentclass 'rapport1':

```
\documentclass[11pt]{rapport1}  
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
```

This documentclass has a default parindent which I managed to erase with the following line:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

This line however seems not to affect the indentation within tikz nodes:

[image: problem]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{rapport1}  
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em,
                     text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em] 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
        \node [block] (test) {This is a test!};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to solve this issue and get the node block rendered just as it would when using `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: I loaded up your image to our default picture service to include it directly. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: I improved the formatting of your code a little: I made your example became copyable ad full working code (not a snippet) and fixed the line width to avoid vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set `\unitindent` to 0 pt instead of changing `\parindent`:

```
\setlength{\unitindent}{0pt}
```

[image: TikZ node]

This is used by the class, in `rapport1.cls` we find

```
\newdimen\unitindent
...
\setlength\parindent{\unitindent}
```

Specifically, `\parindent` can be reset to `\unitindent` by internal class macros, such as `\@indentset`:

```
\newcommand*\@indentset{%
            \global\parindent=\unitindent
            \global\leftmargini=\unitindent
            \global\@needwriteindenttrue}
```